# Cannot connect with FTP server with PHP , ftp_connect()

Tags: php, ftp

I was trying to connect with ftp server using ftp_connect() function of PHP as shown below:

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

?>
```

But it returns this error:

> Warning: ftp_connect() [function.ftp-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in D:\wamp\www\ftp2.php on line 6

Although this is a very common type of error, I still cannot find any solution. Can anyone provide some possible solutions?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must supply only the ftp server hostname, rather than the hostname and directory path, and the irrelevant `http://` since this is an FTP connection.

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.mozilla.org";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// Then chdir to the correct directory:
ftp_chdir($conn_id, "/pub/mozilla.org");
```

See the [full documentation of PHP's FTP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/book.ftp.php).

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. I should've been more careful to documentation. :)

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `http://`, it is not part of the server address.