# Upload files from one server to another server using php not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I have tried in many ways to upload files using FTP functions in PHP. But it is not working for me. I don't know what mistake I made in this code. I have given the local file path or another server file path also, but in both cases it is not working. I have given my code below. Can anyone help to find my problem?

```
/* Source File Name and Path */
$backup_file = '/var/www/html/artbak/assets/uploads/edi/test.txt';
//$backup_file = '/workspace/all-projects/artbak/assets/uploads/edi/test.txt';
$remote_file = $backup_file;

$ftp_host = 'hostname'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'username'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */ 

/* New file name and path for this file */
$local_file = '/public_html/example.txt';

/* Connect using basic FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

/* Login to FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Download $remote_file and save to $local_file */
if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    echo "WOOT! Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}

/* Close the connection */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
```

The below code is working for local to server upload, but not working for server to server upload. It shows the server not connecting. Please give some ideas guys. I am struggling in more in this concept.

```
$ftp_host = 'hostname'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'username'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */ 

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);

$file = "dummy.txt";

$remote_file = "receiveDummy.txt";

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: The given FTP details are destination server , is it correct or i need to source server details?

Comment: Try turning on errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and outputting `error_get_last()` in the `else` branch.

Comment: ok i'll check it. The error shows are ftp_login(), ftp_put() and ftp_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.

Comment: I have checked the FTP details, that are working fine. Then how can i get the error.

Comment: The source path i given was SFTP and destination path is FTP . Is there any problem regarding this. I think so ly not working.

Comment: If you are able to use both FTP protocols, there is [CodeIgniter library](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/ftp.html) can make job done. Otherwise it is pure PHP and not CodeIgniter issue because CI library doesn't support SFTP.

Comment: I have tried the Codelgniter library functions also, but not working. And i have check local system to FTP server upload , that also not working.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a check on the return value of `ftp_connect`. If it returns `false`, as it seems to be doing, the connect has failed. You could check for this after the `ftp_connect` and output `error_get_last` again.

Comment: same errors only coming. Expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given for ftp_login(), ftp_put() and ftp_close(). The error_get_last  not return any errors.

Comment: Now i have solve the server issues, in previously firewall block in server, now it was removed. Now the ftp is connected from php code. But the files not uploading to destination server. ftp_put showing error to no such file or folder in destination server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support guys. I am happy to post this answer couple of days work. Only the thing is need to avoid the destination server path `/public_html/test.txt` instead of `test.txt`. If you have any sub folders give like `sample/test.txt` . Kindly check the below code, it is use full for some one like me.

```
/* Source File Name and Path */
            $remote_file = '/var/www/html/artbak/assets/uploads/edi/test.txt';

            $ftp_host = 'hostname'; /* host */
            $ftp_user_name = 'username'; /* username */
            $ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */ 

            /* New file name and path for this file */
            $local_file = 'test.txt';

            /* Connect using basic FTP */
            $connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

            /* Login to FTP */
            $login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

            /* Download $remote_file and save to $local_file */
            if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
                echo "WOOT! Successfully written to $local_file\n";
            }
            else {
                echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
            }

            /* Close the connection */
            ftp_close( $connect_it );
```

And one thing is in my server had some firewall block, for that reason only first ftp not connecting via php code. Now i solve that issue also. Because my code working in local to server already know. For that i referred the below link to solve the firewall block in server, [Can't connect to FTP with PHP ftp_connect from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462898/cant-connect-to-ftp-with-php-ftp-connect-from-localhost) . So it is working well.